# Non-greedy subgroup Ruby regular expression matching

Tags: ruby, regex, media-type

I'm trying to write a regex to parse the vendor, version, and format components of a media-type string, where the version will be after the final dash. For example:

- matching on `"vnd.mycompany-foo-bar-v1+json"` should produce `['mycompany-foo-bar', 'v1', 'json']`
- matching on `"vnd.mycompany-v1+json"` should produce `['mycompany', 'v1', 'json']`
- matching on `"vnd.mycompany+json"` should produce `['mycompany', nil, 'json']`
- matching on `"vnd.mycompany-foo-bar-v1"` should produce `['mycompany-foo-bar', 'v1', nil]`

So far the closest I've got is

```
/\Avnd\.([a-z0-9*.\-_!#\$&\^]+?)(?:-([a-z0-9*\-.]+))?(?:\+([a-z0-9*\-.+]+))?\z/
```

but matching against "vnd.mycompany-foo_bar-v1+json" gives me `['mycompany', 'foo-bar-v1', 'json']`.

It's the possibly infinite number of dashes that's throwing me for a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Regex:**

```
\Avnd\.(.+?)(?:-([^-+]+))?(?:\+(.*))?\z
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fT5xU9/1)</kbd>

**Break-down:**

- <kbd>`\Avnd\.`</kbd> Matches `vnd.` literally form the start of string
- <kbd>`(.+?)`</kbd> Matches any char, as few as possible times [group 1]
- <kbd>`(?:-([^-+]+))?`</kbd> Optional. Match a `-` followed by any number of chars except `-` and `+`  [group 2]
- <kbd>`(?:\+(.*))?`</kbd> Optional. Match a `+` followed by any chars. [group 3]
- <kbd>`\z`</kbd> Until the end of string.

Comment: The OP correctly used `\A` and `\z`. Why change them to the commonly misused `^` and `$`?

Comment: Why do you use `*` for format component while using `+` for version?

Comment: @sawa `^` and `$` are not incorrect. They match the start and end of string as long as you don't set multiline. As for the quantifiers, it's because, as I interpreted it, a vendor can have a `-`, but it can't have a `+`. Therefore, a `vnd.cpy-` should consider `company = "cpy-"`, whereas `vnd.cpy+` should be treated as an empty format.

Comment: The problem is not that they match the start/end of the string. The problem is that they (unnecessarily) match the start/end of a line. Even though that may not have actual effect, you are making the regex unnecessarily complicated by using `^` and `$`, lowering the readability.

Comment: @sawa My bad. I forgot there's no multiline mode in Ruby. Updated. I do believe the quantifiers are correct though.

Answer (score 0):

If the version is after the *final dash*, then version (and format) can't contain dashes. Just take them out of the character class.

```
/\Avnd\.([a-z0-9*.\-_!#\$&\^]+?)(?:-([a-z0-9*.]+))?(?:\+([a-z0-9*.+]+))?\z/
```